# 3d transform in html 5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

In html5 canvas, is it possible to take a regular 2d image and rotate it backwards so that it will create the effect of 3d surface?

I mean something very simple, just to change the angle of the perspective. Of course, I don't mean to really have a 3d surface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you are not talking about WebGL here soooo...

For 2D canvas graphics, you should try playing with the [**canvas transform methods**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations).  Although there is no way to get a true perspective transform out of them, you can use shearing (the `b` and `c` components of the [**transform matrix**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-settransform)).  See [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Shearing) to get an idea of what you can do with a shear transform and

### See a (stupid) [**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5Djd/8/) too!